# Export model to unity with multiple textures

Tags: modeling, texturing, unity

So I've searched a lot on this topic, but I simply can't seem to find a tutorial explaining how I can add multiple texture to a single model (different textures to each face of for example a cube) an export it into unity3d.

I've found outdated tutorials, where the controls has changed so you cannot do it the way they show.

- All I'm trying to do, is add 3 different textures to a single cube and then import into unity3d with the textures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Answer (score 1):

As a Unity user myself i would say: avoid multiple materials on a single mesh at all times! You are adding unnecessary drawcalls! What you should look into is creating an Atlas, with some smart UV mapping you can avoid this all toghether. There are plenty tutorials for this online.

Otherwise, write a custom fragment shader, but that might be more work then you are looking for.